# How can I remove the dot that haystack returns so that I can use it for my image path

Tags: python-3.x, solr, django-haystack

I am using

```
Django==1.9.4
django-haystack==2.4.1
django-taggit==0.18.0
Pillow==3.1.1
pysolr==3.4.0
pytz==2016.1
python 3.5
```

i just found out that the version of django I'm using isn't supported by haystack yet. So I can't use this

```
results.object.image.url
```

for my src to display an image.

I have to do this

```
 results.image
```

but this displays

```
./car.jpg
```

the work around I had was to do this

```
media/{{result.image}}
```

but that displays

```
media/./car.jpg
```

I want to remove the dot

so it will display like this

```
media/car.jpg
```

tried this as well

```
{{result.image |slice:":1" }}
```

but that makes everything disappear except for the dot

How can I do this? any guidance advice or tutorials to look at are all welcome

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> img = "./car.jpg"
>>> print img[2:]
car.jpg
>>>
```

The [2:] is used to remove the first two character of the string img
 in your case:

```
media/{{result.image[2:]}}
```

Comment: thanks for the response i tried it and it didn't work. This was the error msg "Could not parse the remainder: '[2:]' from 'result.image[2:]' "

Comment: Hmm what is the type of result.image? Could you try str(result.image)[2:] ?

Comment: thanks for the response that doesn't work either. I don't think it can be done. I'll just have to return search results with no pics. Which kind of makes my result seem incomplete